# Python3 - How to Write metadata to a windows media file

Tags: python-3.x, properties, windows-10, metadata, pywin32

I would like to be able to write some metadata to a video, media file in Windows 10 using python3.  Doing some searching online I figured out how to read the metadata with the code below.  Nowhere online could I find any information about writing the data.  I wonder if this is even possible with Python.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon
filename = "Video.mp4"

properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(filename)
title = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Title).GetValue()
print (title)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe you could just use FFmpeg to do that, why does it have to be Python? Check [this](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata) out if you're interested in FFmpeg (which, by the way, you could automate with python)